# quickfix in django Execute multiple functions

Tags: python, django, quickfix

When I run the code, it executes the command and opens the incomming file, but I cannot implement any other function. The file does not exist or cannot be opened.
`
import time
import quickfix
import quickfix44
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render
import threading
from django.http import JsonResponse
from quickfix import Message, MsgType
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
symbol=['EURUSD', 'NZDAUD']
messages=[]
messages1=[]
messages2=[]
should_stop_data_flow = True

```
def messageToString(message):
 ............
def securityListRequest(sessionID):
 ...............

def marketDataRequest(sessionID):
............

class Application(quickfix.Application):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
     
  def onCreate(self, sessionID):
    print("onCreate:")
    self.session_id = sessionID
    target = sessionID.getTargetCompID().getString()
    sender = sessionID.getSenderCompID().getString()
   
    return
  def onLogon(self, sessionID):
  
    self.sessionID = sessionID
    print("onLogon:", f"Session ID: {self.sessionID}")
  
    message = marketDataRequest(sessionID)
    print("market data request:", messageToString(message))
    quickfix.Session.sendToTarget(message, sessionID)

  
def onLogout(self, sessionID):
    print("onLogout..")
    return
def toAdmin(self, message, sessionID):
    print("toAdmin:", messageToString(message), '\n')
    return
def toApp(self, message, sessionID):
  
    print("toApp:", messageToString(message), '\n')
  
    return
def fromAdmin(self, message, sessionID):  
    print("fromAdmin:", messageToString(message), '\n')
    return
 
    def fromApp( self,message, sessionID):

       msg = messageToString(message)
       print("fromApp:", msg, '\n')
    
    
    def keepAlive(self):
        while True:
          time.sleep(30)
def run_fix():
    global app
    settings = quickfix.SessionSettings("CCFIX.ini")
    app = Application()
    storeFactory = quickfix.FileStoreFactory(settings)
    logFactory = quickfix.FileLogFactory(settings)
    initiator = quickfix.SocketInitiator(app, storeFactory, settings, logFactory)
    initiator.start()
    app.keepAlive()

def start_fix_thread():
     fix_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_fix)
    fix_thread.start()

def fix_example_view(request):
     global symbol
     start_fix_thread()       
    return render(request, 'show_messages.html', {'messages': messages})`
```

Answer (score 0):

"The file does not exist or cannot be opened." - that's your answer.

Some line in your code is trying to open a file, and it's not finding that file.  It's probably the "CCFIX.ini" line.  (Don't you have a stacktrace that shows line numbers?)

I'm guessing that your code is not looking in the directory that you think.

Comment: The file exists and works when running the program, but sending a second command shows this error, but continues to execute the first command

Comment: Maybe your first execution is holding open a file handle that is preventing a second execution from concurrently opening it?